# Scrapy crawling issue

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, web-crawler, scrapy, ipython

I am trying to crawl from wikipedia but the result is not returning anything.
 I tried running simple query in IPython console with one value to check but still it is not returning any value.

I have tried this:

`sel.xpath('//div[@id="mw-content-text"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/text()').extract()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to be a guess, but an educated one. `tbody` is something inserted by a browser and something you see in the Browser Developer Tools. But, Scrapy is not a browser - *remove `tbody` from the xpath expression*:

```
sel.xpath('//div[@id="mw-content-text"]/table/tr[1]/td[1]/text()').extract()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! It is working now! I will remember this educated  guess! Thanks again! :)